# Grabbing names of object of out a JSON object in javascript and storing it in an String Array

Tags: javascript, json, string

So the issues that I am currently having is a string manipulation logic issue. My goal is to store the names of JSON objects in a string array. So it will be easier to access the data later on. But the current issue that I am running into is that the output is nothing that I want or understand of how it is getting it. Currently I am looking for the quotes between the object names and returning it to a string using str.substring, and storing it in an index of newArr. The output equals in 4th code snippet. I have also tried putting an underscore before and after the object name in the JSON object, then searching for the underscore. From my testing this will only work with the first name, which will return "foo" in index 0, while the rest of the indexes equal to '"_'. I know there is something wrong with my logic in the function, but I can not pinpoint what it is. Any help would be appreciated

This is the function that is being ran.

```
exports.jsonObjectToArray = function (objectToTurn){
var oldArr = JSON.stringify(objectToTurn).split(","),
    firstIndex,
    secondIndex,
    newArr = [];
for(let i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i ++){
  firstIndex = oldArr[i].indexOf("\"");
  secondIndex = oldArr[i].indexOf(firstIndex, "\"");
  newArr[i] = oldArr[i].substring(firstIndex, secondIndex);
}
return newArr;
  }
```

When the function is ran oldArr will equal to this value.

```
[ '{"foo":"',
'"bar":"0"',
'"Mar":"0"',
'"Car":"0"}' 
]
```

And my goal is to return this. Which will be stored in newArr.

```
[ 
"foo",
"bar",
"Mar",
"Car"
]
```

But after the function runs this is what I get returned.

```
[ 
 '{"', 
 'bar":"0',
 'Mar":"0', 
 'Car":"0'
]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the keys from the object? Just use `Object.keys()`

Comment: would Object.keys return the names of the object?

Comment: If by names you mean `foo,bar,mar,car`, then yes. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: How many variations do we need of "I want to get blah blah from some JSON" do we need?  This one in particular was ridiculously trivial, and really most need to be closed as duplicates, not "answered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the keys from an object, simply use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Quick example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: '1',
    bar: '2',
    car: '3'
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj)); // ==> (3) ["foo", "bar", "car"]
```

Comment: Thank you, Maybe next time I should look to see if there a method that is already created for me.

Answer (score 0):

let arr = [ '{"foo":"',
'"bar":"0"',
'"Mar":"0"',
'"Car":"0"}' 
]

let arr1 = arr.map(el => el.split('"')[1])